Why does higher variance between clusters increase the power to detect the effect in Poisson mixed GLM?
I simulated the dataset below and I am trying to fit the Poisson GLMM with random intercepts and calculate the power to detect the effect of $x$.
When I increase the variance between the clusters ($0.5$ vs $4$), I get higher power to detect the effect of $x$ ($0.817$ vs $0.904$, respectively) which seems counterintuitive (at least to me). Is there a mistake in my code or is it expected? If this is expected, what is the explanation?
library(lme4)

set.seed(123)
nsim <- 1000
var <- 4
N <- 100
pvalues <- numeric(nsim)
alpha <- 0.05

for(k in 1:nsim){
  groups <- 1:5
  g <- factor(sample(groups, replace = TRUE, size = N), levels = groups)
  x <- rnorm(N)
  X <- model.matrix(~ x)
  Z <- model.matrix(~ g - 1)
  beta <- c(2, 0.1)
  gamma <- rnorm(length(groups), 0, sqrt(var))
  y <-  rpois(N,exp(X %*% beta + Z%*% gamma))
  model <- glmer(y ~ x + (1|g), family="poisson")
  pvalues[k] <- summary(model)$coef[2,4]
}
power <- mean(pvalues < alpha)

